# Mockito on continuous Optional classes

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

This is the code block I'm working with:

```
Optional<Response> response = something.get();
Optional<String> content = response.map(Response::getContent);
ObjectNode head = objectMapper.readValue(content.get(), ObjectNode.class);

// then I'm going to work with this "head"
```

I got `Cannot mock/spy class java.util.Optional` before, so I know I cannot mock Optional. Since I don't have "something", I'm doing:

```
@Mock private Something something;
@Mock Response res;

when(something.get()).thenReturn(Optional.of(res));
```

But I don't know how to mock the next two lines.

I have constructed a "head" and I want to test with this one I created.

Hope I make myself clear. Thanks!

Comment: Line 2 (`Optional<String> content = response.map(Response::getContent);`): `when(res.getContent()).thenReturn("SomeContent");` --- Line 3 (`ObjectNode head = objectMapper.readValue(content.get(), ObjectNode.class);
`) will require you to mock an `ObjectMapper` and mock its response whne called with `"SomeContent"` and `ObjectNode.class` as parameters.

Comment: Alternatively, you can provide a valid `String`-representation ob an `ObjectNode`-instance (I presume JSON) and substitute it for `"SomeContent"`. This would eliminate the necessity to mock the `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks! It works. The first way with a mocked objectMapper works well. And the "SomeContent" I'm providing is already a `String` representation of a JsonObject. If I want to try your alternative solution, should I just comment out `when(objectMapper.readValue("SomeContent", ObjectNode.class).thenReturn(myConstructedHead)`?

Comment: I actually get the myConstructedHead by `ObjectNode myConstructedHead = mapper.readValue("SomeContent", ObjectNode.class)`. But the alternative way is giving me a null value as the returned `head` if I comment the line mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: If `"SomeContent"` is indeed a valid `String`-representation of `ObjectNode`, then yes, remove the mocking for the `ObjectMapper` and just pass a "real" `ObjectMapper` to the unit under test.

Comment: Oh I see! I got null because I'm using the mocked `objectMapper` but I should give a "real" one for test! Thank you! This problem has blocked me for hours!